# Setting the time for messages in the minibuffer

Tags: minibuffer

Messages that appear in the minibuffer disappear too quickly for me to read them. I would like them to last a few more seconds before disappearing. (I know I can press C-h e to see them again.) I forgot which setting to tweak for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change the value of the variable *suggest-key-bindings*. Default value is 2

Comment: That was just what I was looking for. I ended up setting suggest-key-bindings to off.